# Square roots of $-1$ in quaternion ring

Tags: quaternions

In [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Square_roots_of_.E2.88.921) it is said that the square roots of -1 in the quaternion ring are the elements of the imaginary sphere. I don't understand why this is so. I don't understand the system that's written there. If I do

$$(a+bi+cj+dk)^2=a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2+2(ab+cd)i+2(ac-bd)j+2(ad+bc)k=-1$$

the system we get is

$$\begin{cases} a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2=-1 \\ ab+cd=0 \\ ac-bd=0 \\ ad+bc=0 \end{cases}$$

I suppose this could be solved to get the same solution, but it is quite tiresome and I'd like to understand how to get to the prettier system the Wikipedia gives.

Comment: The norm of a quaternion is multiplicative i.e. $|q_1q_2|=|q_1||q_2|$, so if the square is $-1$, the norm squared is $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$.  So your first equation tells you that the only way this can be true is if $a^2=0$, i.e. $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$.  Oh, and your last three equations are wrong, it's not $ab+cd=0$, it's $ab=0$.  This is because when you multiply-out your first line $jk=-kj$, so the two terms with $cd$ in them cancel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add your first equation to $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ and you get $a=0$, whence $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$.

Then observe

$$(b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k})^2=-(b^2+c^2+d^2)+(cd-dc)\mathbf{i}+(db-bd)\mathbf{j}+(bc-cb)\mathbf{k} $$
$$=-1+0\mathbf{i}+0\mathbf{j}+0\mathbf{k}=-1.$$
Hence any quaternion $\mathbf{q}=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$ with $a=0,b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ is a square root of $-1$. The error in your calculations is that you didn't take into account anticommutativity, i.e.
$$(c\mathbf{j})(d\mathbf{k})=cd\;\mathbf{i}\quad\text{but}\quad (d\mathbf{k})(c\mathbf{j})=-dc\;\mathbf{i}.$$

Answer (score 8):

They have it right. You have not been careful enough in $\pm$ signs. The coefficient of $i$ does begin with $2ab$ as you say, but then we get
$$ c j d k + d k c j = c d i - c d i=0.$$ And so forth.

Comment: Ouch, I found my mistake. I must remember that the binomial theorem only works in *commutative* rings. Thank you!