# Why does $i$ have infinitely many conjugates in $\mathbb{H}$?

Tags: quaternions

Browsing this question: [Why are the solutions of polynomial equations so unconstrained over the quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/why-are-the-solutions-of-polynomial-equations-so-unconstrained-over-the-quaterni), the pdf linked in the comments says that the infinitely many conjugates of $i$ in $\mathbb{H}$ are roots to $x^2+1$.

I get that they're roots, but how do we know that the conjugacy class of $i$ is in fact infinite?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the conjugacy class of $i$?

Comment: Calculate $$(\cos\alpha +\sin\alpha j)^{-1}i(\cos\alpha +\sin\alpha j).$$

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but it came up too long.

I think there's a confusion here: the quaternion $\,i\,$ has one unique *quaternionian* conjugate in $\,\Bbb H\,$, as we can deduce from this [definition](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/functions/index.htm)

The sense in which the term "conjugate" seems to be used in the OP is that the minimal polynomial of $\,i\,$ over $\,\Bbb H\,$ has *infinite* other roots, all of which are "conjugate" to (i.e., roots of the same minimal polynomial of) $\,i\,$

So the question doesn't seem to be connected to conjugacy classes a la group theory but with roots of minimal polynomials.

Comment: Hmm. Are you thinking about conjugates in a group of 8 elements? I was thinking about conjugates in the infinite group of invertible quaternions. Edit: Oh, you were referring to the antiautomorphism of $\mathbb{H}$. Sorry. Still, in the group theoretic sense $i$ has infinitely many conjugates.

Comment: As far as I know $\,\Bbb H\,$ usually denotes the infinite division ring of quaternions, and $\,Q_8\,$ the group of quaternions of order $\,8\,$...and no: I wasn't referring to group theoretic meaning but to the quaternionian meaning as in the linked definition.

Comment: Quite. I realized what you had meant, but decided to leave the comment anyway. Talking about a conjugacy *class* does suggest that the OP is interested in the group theoretic version of "conjugate".

Answer (score 0):

$$(a+bi+cj+dk)^2+1=0$$
$$a^2+1 + b^2i^2+c^2j^2+d^2k^2+2abi+2acj+2adk+(bcij+cbji)+(cdjk+dckj)+(bdik+dbki)=0$$
The last three brackets are all $0$. The $i,j,k$ components must all be zero as well, which we can do by setting $a=0$. We're left with
$$1-b^2-c^2-d^2=0$$
which can be satisfied for infinitely many $b,c,d$.

DonAntonio seems to have covered the issue about quaternion conjugates quite nicely, if that's more what you were asking.