# $x^2+1=0$ uncountable many solutions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, quaternions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the solutions of polynomial equations so unconstrained over the quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/why-are-the-solutions-of-polynomial-equations-so-unconstrained-over-the-quaterni)

Coudl someone explain me the following: Why should $x^2+1=0$ have uncountable infinite many solutions $x\in\mathbb H$?

In my opinion it has only 4 solutions, namely $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ ?

Comment: If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ then $ai+bj+ck$ is solution of this equation.

Comment: Math is not really about opinions. If you think there are only four solutions, try and prove that every solution is one of those four. If you get stuck it might be a good start on a counterexample, or a proof that there are uncountably many solutions after all. If you succeed, then it's not an opinion anymore (beware of false proofs, though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $0 \leq p \leq 1$, and consider numbers of the form
$$x = \sqrt p i + \sqrt{1-p} j$$
Taking the square, we have
$$x^2 = (\sqrt p i + \sqrt{1-p} j)^2 = pi^2 + (1-p)j^2 + \sqrt{p(1-p)}(ij + ji)$$
The third term is zero, since $ij = -ji$. The first two terms sum to -1, so any number of the given form is a solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$. Since there are uncountably many $p \in [0,1]$, there are uncountably many solutions.

Comment: Thanks, this seems clear to me. Was it intuition considering numbers of the form $x = \sqrt p i + \sqrt{1-p} j$$

Comment: @Voyage I first tried the form $pi + (1-p)j$, and when I saw where that went wrong it was clear that taking square roots would make it work.

Answer (score 13):

Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers satisfying $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ and let $x = ai + bj + ck$. Then
$$
x^2 = (ai + bj + ck)(ai + bj + ck) = -(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = -1.
$$