# non-trivial solutions to $x^2=x$ in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

We know that when a ring is an integral domain, we have that:

$$x^2=x \implies x^2-x = 0 \implies x(x-1) = 0$$

Since this is an integral domain, a product giving $0$ forces one of the the terms in the product to be $0$, therefore the solutions are:

$$x=0, x -1 = 0$$

However, what about when we have a ring but that's not an integral domain, can we find solutions to this equations such that neither of the two terms are $0$?

Comment: Elements like these are called idempotent elements. Look them up.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_6$, have $3^2 = 9 = 3$.

Comment: As it happens I chatted about the solutions of this very equation in [my answer to a question about zero divisors](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/441833/11619). I didn't even attempt to paint a comprehensive picture. I'm sure the congruence $x^2\equiv x \pmod n$ has been studied elsewhere on our site, but my search fu is weak today. You can try your hand with general $n$ with the aid of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: This is probably one of [the earliest incarnations of the question of  finding the solutions of $x^2\equiv x\pmod n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/175963/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. In $\mathbb{Z}_6$ let $x=3$. Then $x^2 - x = 9-3 = 6 = 0$. Of course $3\neq 0\wedge (3-1)\neq 0$.

It is possible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, if $n = k(k-1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 5):

This means the ring has  a non-trivial idempotent. It corresponds to a decomposition of the ring, let's call it $R$ as a product of rings. If $e$ is such an idempotent, we have 
$$R\simeq Re\times R(1-e)$$
$e$ and $1-e$ are the units of the rings $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ respectively. W.r.t. the ring $R$, they're orthogonal idempotents. A simple example is the product of two fields.

Topologically, $\DeclareMathOperator{\spec}{Spec}\spec R=\spec(Re)\cup\spec R(1-e)$ is a partition of $\spec R$ in two open sets. We see $\;\spec R\;$ is connected if and only if $R$  has non non-trivial idempotents.
bg)

In the domain of non-commutative algebra, the results are analog, but correspond to a decomposition of $R$ as a *module*. We obtain a *ring* decomposition if we have *central* idempotents.

Comment: In case anyone interprets the question in noncommutative context, it should be said that idempotents correspond to *module* decompositions of $R$, while the ring decompositions correspond to *central idempotents*

Comment: @rschwieb: I'll add that, thanks for explaining. I don't know well non commutative algebra, and I seldom venture on these lands…

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=A_1\times A_2$ a product of two rings. Then $(1,0)^2=(1,0)$ and $(0,1)^2=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

A [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) is, by definition, a ring in which *every* element is idempotent. Since any Boolean algebra defines a Boolean rings (and conversely), there are plenty of examples.