# Ideals in the polynomial ring over a division ring are free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $k$ be a division ring. I want to show that every (right) ideal in $k[x]$ is free considered as a right $k[x]$-module.

That means if $I$ is an ideal in $k[x]$ we have to show that $I=f\cdot k[x]$ for an $f\in I$. My first intention was to use the divison algorithm, but as $k$ is just a division ring I guess it won't work?

Maybe somebody can help me with this...

Thanks!

Comment: Don't *guess* that it won't work, try it out and figure out if it *does* work or not. If it doesn't work you'll find out why it doesn't work along the way.

Comment: +1 to rschwieb's comment and answer for giving you the key piece of advice. You are right in that there are caveats. For further encouragement and bits about the caveats I recommend that you take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122953/11619) by Arturo Magidin.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for that interesting link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You're on the right track since you should be able to show that $k[x]$ is a principal right ideal domain. You can mimic the proof for fields that $F[x]$ is a PID, which you probably have seen by now.

Once you show all the right ideals of $k[x]$ are principal, consider such an ideal $aR$. If $aR\neq  0$, then of course $a\neq 0$, and there is a very suggestive mapping here from $R\to aR$ that you should investigate.

Comment: Sorry for guessing and thank you for that hint!  But there is no difference between showing that $k[x]$ ist a principal right ideal domain and showing that all ideals are free modules, right?

Comment: @Heffalump For commutative rings, it's true that if all right ideals are free, then you are looking at a PID. **BUT** for noncommutative rings, there exist rings whose right ideals are all free, but they are not principal right ideal domains. [This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_ideal_ring) talks a little about such rings, but don't worry about learning too much there :)

Comment: Or is the fact that for $R=k[x]$ and $a\neq 0$ the map $R\rightarrow aR$ is an isomorphism important for knowing that the module is free? In other words, are there principle ideals which aren't free considered as a module? for example in a ring which has zero-divisors?

Comment: I wrote my last comment after reading yours...

Comment: @Heffalump For any domain with nonzero $a$, $R\cong aR$, and indeed, all principal right ideals are free. Principal right ideal domains certainly have all right ideals free, then. I'm just saying that there *is* a difference between the two, since there are free ideal rings that aren't principal right ideal rings.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks!