# Factor theorem & noncommutative division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]Show that the factor theorem is false in $R[x]$ if $ R  $ is a noncommutative division ring.

I started with $f = bx - ba $ where $ab \neq ba $ 
What should I do next?

Comment: What do you call "the factor theorem" to?

Comment: Oooh, that! Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Do you know how to do the next step?

Comment: Do you mean *left* ideal in $\;f\in\langle x-a\rangle\;$ ?

Comment: See [this answer by Arturo Magidin](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122953/11619) for more discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine:

$$f(x)=bx-ba\implies f(a)=ba-ba=0$$

If we had that $\;f(x)=(x-a)q(x)\;$ , then it must be $\;q(x)=q\in R\;$ a constant (why?) , so

$$bx-ba=(x-a)q=xq-aq\stackrel{\text{def. of identical pol's}}\implies\begin{cases}b=q\\{}\\ba=aq\end{cases}\;\implies qa=aq$$

contradicting that $\;ba\neq ab\;$ .