# Polynomial: Number of solutions

Tags: calculus

Functions of polynomials often have more than one solution. For example, $x^2 = b$ with positive $b$ has two solutions for $x$.

How does that work for higher polynomials? Say, I have for positive $a,b,c$ and natural $y$

$$ (ax + b)^y = c \\
x_0 = \frac{c^{1/y}-b}{a}$$

Clearly, $x_0$ is one solution. How can I find potential *real* additional  solutions for $y > 1$?

Comment: Are you talking about real solutions, or are you also interested in complex solutions?

Comment: Hint. Look up "fundamental theorem of algebra". The wikipedia page is a good place to start.

Comment: Which are you interested in, finding the number of solutions or finding solutions?  These are very different questions.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137190/is-there-a-polynomial-that-has-infinitely-many-roots/1137202#1137202) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @RobertIsrael both, to be honest. But I guess the number of distinct solutions is a start.

Comment: @Meelo I am aware that it has *at most* $y$ roots. I'd like to check how many root it exactly has. (I thought that was the same as finding the distinct solutions, but apparently it is not)

Comment: @FooBar Ah. [Sturm's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) handles that (over the reals).

Comment: For real and the given example: if y is odd than one, if even than two. If you allow complex solution, than you have y.

Comment: @Moti I think that settles it for me here. If you'd post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real and the given example: if y is odd than one, if even than two. If you allow complex solution, than you have y