# Why does $\langle 0 \rangle$ not correspond to a projective variety for finite fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Exercise 5.3.22 of [Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach](http://bookstore.ams.org/stml-66) asks:

> Show that $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ is a projective variety when $k$ is an infinite field.

This is easy -- $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ corresponds to the zero set of $\langle 0 \rangle$, which is always prime since fields are always integral domains, and thus polynomial rings over fields are always integral domains.

Usually the cardinality of a field is important because, for finite fields, there exist non-zero polynomials which evaluate to $0$ at every point of the space ([e.g. see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961032/why-is-cardinality-of-the-field-important-for-noetherian-normalization)). But I don't see why that matters here -- even if $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ could possibly be generated as the zero set of an even larger ideal than just $\langle 0 \rangle$ for finite fields, that still doesn't mean that $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ isn't a projective variety, right?

**Question:** Do I actually need to use the hypothesis that $k$ is infinite to show this?

Comment: What is your definition of projective variety ? For me a projective variety is an algebraic closed subset of $\Bbb P^n(k)$, and then it's true that $\Bbb P^n(k)$ is a projective variety for any field $k$.

Comment: @N.H. Good point. The definition of projective variety in my book is an _irreducible_ algebraic subset of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$. When you say closed, do you mean in the Zariski topology, i.e. that the ideal generated by the set is a prime ideal? Because by a previous exercise in the section, which shows that an algebraic set is irreducible if and only if its ideal is prime, then our definitions coincide. So I guess my question is not so much about whether $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ is a projective variety for any field $k$, but whether the proof I propose needs to be modified for finite fields.

Comment: Ok, then yes your proof works exactly the same.

Comment: @N.H. I appreciate the sanity check -- enjoy the rest of your weekend!

Comment: Sure, have a good week end too ! (I have a terrible exam to prepare haha)

Comment: if your projective varieties are *subsets* of $\Bbb P^n(k)$ without any algebraic structure attached, then over finite fields this is not particularly interesting as every subset is an algebraic subset

Comment: @mercio A projective variety is the zero locus of a prime homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$.