# Polynomial division when both polynomials are $ \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $ and the divisor is monic.

Tags: polynomials

Define polynomials $P$ and $D$ such that $ P, D \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $, and D is monic. Prove (or disprove) that the quotient of $\frac{P(x)}{D(x)}$ is $\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding divison by monic polynomial in $R[x]$ where $R$ is an arbitrary ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811541/understanding-divison-by-monic-polynomial-in-rx-where-r-is-an-arbitrary-ri)

Comment: @Michael oh ok thank you