# Polynomial with infinite roots

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I started Ring theory recently and I came across this statement while reading polynomial rings..

> If $F$ is an infinite field and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ . If $f(a)=0$ for infinitely many elements $a$ of $F$, then $f(x)=0$

I have the following doubt. Take $\Bbb{Q}$ as the infinite field. Now define $$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (x-i)$$

Since (as far as I know , but I may be wrong!) the degree of polynomials need not necessarily be finite, $f(x)$ is polynomial $\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ and $f(a)=0$ for infinitely many elements in $\Bbb{Q}$. So where am I making a mistake?

Comment: The degree has to be finite: a polynomial has only finitely many non-zero coefficients. However you can see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689061).

Comment: @Watson Is it in the definition of a poynomial? Google doesn't say so I think! [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=definition+of+a+polynomial&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN696IN696&oq=definition+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j0l3.2607j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Then google is inaccurate in this case.  I don't recommend using Google to look up math definitions.  The mathematical definition of a polynomial requires finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: @tilper Okay .. I see.. i thought Google was always perfect..

Comment: @Qwerty Well, I don't think there is any problem with Googling math definitions. In fact, Google can and should be an indispensable tool for learning lots of things. The mistake you made was to only read the first thing at the top and assume it was correct. Reading the next five links should have cast light on the problems with the first thing you read, and convinced you that you need to keep reading to find a clear definition.

Comment: What is the definition of the polynomial ring $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ in your textbook?

Comment: @BillDubuque The set of formal symbols $R[x]=\{a_nx^n+\cdots +a_1x+a_0|a_i\in R,\ n$ is a **non-negative integer** $\}$ is called  the ring of polynomials over $R$

Answer (score 1):

The degree must be finite, otherwise $\sum \limits _{n = 0} ^\infty \frac {x^n} {n!}$ would be a polynomial - which clearly it isn't, being $\Bbb e^x$.

In fact, a polynomial is just a function from $\Bbb N$ to $F$ with *finite* support.

Comment: I asked google the definition of a polynomial and it didnt mention anything about its degree..[link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=definition+of+a+polynomial&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN696IN696&oq=definition+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j0l3.2607j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Qwerty: Google says *"sum of several terms"* and sums, by definition, have a finite number of terms. When there are infinitely many summands, those are *series*.

Comment: @Qwerty I see four hits for "degree" on the page you linked, so your claim that "it didn't mention anything about degrees" looks pretty silly.

Comment: @rschwieb Okay. I am sorry to have judged Google superficially.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, which must have a fixed, but arbitrary degree $n\ge 0$. It is a theorem then, that every polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$ has at most $n$ zeros. This is no longer true over, say, a skew-field. Consider the polynomial $x^2+1$ over the quaternion algebra, as an example - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/why-are-the-solutions-of-polynomial-equations-so-unconstrained-over-the-quaterni). It has infinitely many roots.

Comment: but google doesnt say so ! [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=definition+of+a+polynomial&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN696IN696&oq=definition+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j0l3.2607j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Google does say so, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial), section "Definition".

Comment: I got it. But it is Wikipedia....Anyways ..thanks

Comment: Can a polynomial over a skew field have infinitely many roots, or does one need to take even less well-behaved rings for that?

Comment: For the skew field of quaternions this can happen - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/why-are-the-solutions-of-polynomial-equations-so-unconstrained-over-the-quaternions).

Comment: Ahh, thanks (I was thinking whether one needed to go so some infinite product of fields or such for this).

Comment: @Qwerty What's wrong with wikipedia? As a rule, the content is pretty good, especially with mathematics. Again, the only mistake you can make is to treat wikipedia (or any single page on the internet) like scripture. There is no harm at all with using it as a starting point and refining what you learned with other content. Quite often you will find that it's good.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the tip!