# There is a field $\Bbb F$ such that the equation $x^2=1$ have more than two solutions (for some $x\in\Bbb F$)?

Tags: field-theory, roots-of-unity

> There is a field $\Bbb F$ such that the equation $x^2=1$ have more than two solutions (for some $x\in\Bbb F$)?

This question comes suddenly to my mind.

I know that if $\Bbb F=\Bbb C$ then the fundamental theorem of algebra states that the equation $x^2=1$ have two solutions, but this would imply that for an arbitrary field $x^2=1$ have, at most, two solutions?

Im sorry if this question is trivial but at this moment Im unable to achieve a conclusion from the axioms that define a field.

Comment: In any field, a polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots.

Comment: Well, in a *division ring* (skew field) it can occur, e.g. among the quaternions, $x^2=1$ has infinitely many solutions

Comment: If $x_1^2=1$ and $x_2^2=1$ then $0=x_1^2-x_2^2=(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)$. From there you get that either $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1=-x_2$.

Comment: @Berci:  are you sure about that?

Comment: @RobertLewis: No.. but $x^2=-1$ has infinitely many solutions for sure, all purely imaginary unit quaternions. At first I thought we just multiply all solutions by $i$ to get solutions for $x^2=1$, but that was wrong because of noncommutativity..

Comment: Extensive discussion of this at : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/why-are-the-solutions-of-polynomial-equations-so-unconstrained-over-the-quaterni , which also discusses why $x^2=k$  can have uncountably many solutions in a skew field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ solves

$x^2 = 1, \tag{1}$

so that

$\alpha^2 = 1, \tag{2}$

or

$\alpha^2 -1 = 0, \tag{3}$

we have

$(\alpha - 1)(\alpha + 1) = 0; \tag{4}$

if now

$\alpha \ne 1, \tag{5}$

so that

$\alpha -1 \ne 0, \tag{6}$

then since we are operating in a field,

$\alpha + 1 = 0, \tag{7}$

or

$\alpha = -1. \tag{8}$

At most two possibilities.  And that's all.

Answer (score 5):

No: over an `integral domain`, a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

This is a consequence of the fact that a polynomial $p$ is divisible by $X-\alpha$ if and only if $p(\alpha)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2=1$ then $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, and since $F$ is a field either $x-1=0$ or $x+1=0$.

In general, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial over a field $F$ of degree $n$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots in $F$.

Answer (score 3):

No, in any field $x^2 = 1$ iff $x^2-1 = 0$ iff $(x-1)(x+1) = 0$ and in a field (no zero-divisors) this means that either $x-1 = 0$ (so $x=1$) or $x+1 = 0$ (so $x=-1$).

Comment: oh, ok... I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $x^2 = 1 \iff (x-1)(x+1) = 0$ and a field is an integral domain

Answer (score 1):

In any non zero ring $R$ with $1$, which has no nonzero zero divisors, $x^2=1$ has exactly $1$ root if $char(R)=2$ and exactly 2 roots if $char(R)\neq2$.