# Analog of finite set in valued complete division ring

Tags: analysis, p-adic-number-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Let $K$ be a complete valued division ring and $S$ be a compact subset of $D$. It is easy to see that if $K$ is commuative, the $K$-algebra $\mathscr C(S,K)$ of continuous functions on $S$ in $K$ is $K[x]$ if and only if $S$ is finite.
Does one have such a characterization on $S$ when $K$ is not commutative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is $K[x]$"?  Maybe you mean that every continuous function is given by a polynomial?  Note that this does not mean that $\mathscr{C}(S,K)$ is isomorphic to $K[x]$ though since the map from $K[x]$ may not be injective.

Comment: Yes, I meant that every continuous function is given by a polynomial.

Comment: Interesting question (when fixed as suggested above). Indeed, for either implication, I run into the problems discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122898/96384.

Comment: May I ask what is the motivation for this? Precisely because of the problems discussed in the link above, standard polynomials (where the variable commutes with coefficients) are an unnatural object and a not very helpful tool over non-commutative rings, even division rings. Instead, something like skew polynomials might make a good replacement.

Comment: standard polynomials are not skew polynomials (for the identity endomorphism and the null derivation)?

Comment: They are a special case which, as explained in that link, do not work well here. The basic problem is that evaluation does not commute with multiplication. But now I think that even more non-trivial skew polynomials will not repair that, because there the variable $x$ would have a *fixed* commutation relation, which is not true after evaluating $x$ at arbitrary elements ... rather, one would need an object like $D\langle x\rangle$ explained in Qiaochu Yuan's answer and Arturo Magidin's comment in there. But then it's totally unclear to me how to perform calculations in that algebra.